# How on earth can this proposal be only at 29% definition when it has over 200 commits?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase, commitment-fulfillment

After browsing around on area51, I noticed that the proposal, Stackoverflow in Korean, has over 200 commits, but is only about 29% to beta.

[image]

Then there's there's this proposal, Startups, with less than 190 commits, but it's 90% to beta.

[image]

What's up with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on "more info" in the side bar, you will see why:

[image: commitment stats for Korean.SE]

Specifically, the reason that it is 29% is because you only have 29% of the necessary users with at least 200 rep on another SE site.  The % Commitment is always the lowest of the 3 shown values, and the site won't graduate to the private beta phase until all 3 criteria are at 100%.

The Startups proposal that you are comparing too on the other hand, has a much different view.  It is only missing a few committers (19 of the 200 to be exact), which is why it is at 90%.

[image: commitment stats for startups]

Comment: As a side note, given the language sites usually have other issues than just the commitment due to localization, it is likely that Korean.SO won't move to private beta immediately when it gets to 100%.  It will probably take several months or more. (SO in Russian, Turkish, and Spanish have been waiting for some time)